# error guzzlehttp when try to install google cloud vision in laravel using composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I want to use Google Cloud Vision and I follow tutorial on the Internet. I need to install google cloud `composer require wapnen/google-cloud-vision-php` then error appear, the error shows

```
- wapnen/google-cloud-vision-php dev-master requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.3.2, 6.3.3, 6.4.0, 6.4.1, 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 6.5.x-dev].
```

Can anyone tell how to solve this problem? I've tried to find guzzle 6.3.0 but I couldn't find it, Thank you for your answer

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? Is there another package requiring an older version of Guzzle? And could you output everything from your terminal? I think this is just a part (?)

Comment: Why do you want to install a dev version of that package? Why not use a stable one? And also, `guzzlehttp/guzzle` is listed on Packagist with multiple versions, including 6.3.0